# rounding of numbers using R

Tags: r, data-munging

I want to convert the following numbers in this way I tried to use all possible methods but i am unable to get the value which i expected

```
value        round off value
0.0 - 4.9         0
5.0 - 5.9         6
6.0 - 6.9         7
7.0 - 7.9         8
8.0 - 8.9         9
9.0 - 10.0        10
```

The above table is for reference

```
expected output  eg :- roundup(5.0) = 6  ,roundup(6.9)=7
```

Comment: so your input numbers are numeric (e.g., 4.3) or they are represented as intervals?

Comment: No I am just giving reference but the expected output must be like eg :- roundup(5.0) = 6  ,roundup(6.9)=7

Comment: Try `roundup<-function(x) c(0,6:10)[findInterval(x,c(0,5:9))]`.

Comment: Awesome @nicola can you add in New answer section so it will be helpful for other devlopers

Comment: @Dr.jeon I posted an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
roundup<-function(x) c(0,6:10)[findInterval(x,c(0,5:9))]
roundup(c(5,6.9))
#[1] 6 7
```